# Why is my Linked List assignment not working as it should?

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers

So I made a linked list class:

```
class node {
public:
    string name;
    node *next;
    node(string init) {name = init; next = nullptr;
};
```

and then in main I created a node pointer and initialized the name of the node it points to.

```
node *root;
root->name = "Hello"; //Error
```

The compiler doesn't call this an error, but when I run the program it stops working at this line of code. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I posted then deleted the answer you have **typo** in your question, Missing `}`.

Comment: What node that it points to? Why do you think it points to a node?

Comment: oh sorry for the typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate the a `node` object for `root` to point to.

```
node* root = new node;
```

But be careful, now you have to make sure to call `delete` on `root` at the right moment. You coudl simplify things by using a smart pointer, or an automatic storage object

```
node root;
root.name = "Hello";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This brings me to another question, though. Is there any way to write a class destructor so that all elements of the list are deleted, or do I have to have a separate function for that?

Comment: @user2457666 yes, of course. Look up destructors. Also, there are many linked list related questions on SO.